# why my accuracy and recall become higher in testing than training. How to interpret

Tags: neural-network, overfitting, confusion-matrix

[image: all the model I try]

Why in hidden layer 2 and 3 in neural networks scratch, the accuracy and recall I got low, but in testing the accuracy and recall become higher. In hidden layer 4 it's get weird when sampling strategy = 0.3 get higher accuracy than sampling strategy = 0.9 but have the same value in recall testing.

These are the confusion matrix from hidden layer 2 and 3:
with sampling strategy 0.3 =
training {    TN 0   FN  0 FP 13407  TP 3997}
testing {'TP': 1023, 'FP': 3329, 'TN': 0, 'FN': 0}

with sampling strategy 0.9 =
training {TN    0     FP 0 FN 13416 TP 12022}
testing {'TP': 3040, 'FP': 3320, 'TN': 0, 'FN': 0}

These are confusion matrix from hidden layer 4:
with sampling strategy 0.3 =
training {    0     FN0 FP 13407  TP 3997}                                                      testing {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'TN': 3329, 'FN': 1023}

with sampling strategy 0.9 =
training {    TN 0     FN 0 FP 13416 TP 12022}
testing {'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'TN': 3320, 'FN': 3040}

From what I know that in hidden layer 4 the model get overfitting but I can't explain higher accuracy in sampling strategy 0.3 than sampling strategy 0.9.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden layer 3"? Did you try different models with different number of hidden layers?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your test set has not been sampled properly. You might have similar or the same cases for all of your testing data points. Or it is also possible if your testing split is very small.